# transfer listbox values to particular rows and column to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

i am writing a code to transfer list box data to new excel workbook. it is working by populating new worksheet from row 2 and particular column. what i want is, list should be populating from row 23 in particular column. i have tried to search but unable to make it work. my code is as below,

```
Private Sub cmdprint_Click()

Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim xlwbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet

xl.DisplayAlerts = False


Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\filename.xlsm")
Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item("output")

Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 2


 With UserForm1.lstdatabase1
For i = 0 To UserForm1.lstdatabase1.ListCount - 1
        
        With xlsheet
        
         .Cells(j, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = UserForm1.lstdatabase1.List(i, 1) 'column 1
         .Cells(j, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = UserForm1.lstdatabase1.List(i, 2) 'column 2
         j = j + 1
    End With
    
   
  xlwbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\File name (i want this to be value from userform text box")
  
  
  
   xl.DisplayAlerts = True
   
    'no need to carry on searching
    
Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Also, i would like to save file save as Textbox value from form, instead of fix name.
can you pl help me with that.
thanks

Comment: Try replacing `.Cells(j, 7)` with `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 7)` and `.Cells(j, 8)` with `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 8)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Private Sub cmdprint_Click()

Dim xl As New Excel.Application
Dim xlwbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet

xl.DisplayAlerts = False


Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\filename.xlsm")
Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item("output")

Dim i As Long , j As Long

j = 23


 With UserForm1.lstdatabase1
For i = 0 To UserForm1.lstdatabase1.ListCount - 1
        
        With xlsheet
        
         .Cells(j, 7).Value = UserForm1.lstdatabase1.List(i, 1) 'column 1
         .Cells(j, 8).Value = UserForm1.lstdatabase1.List(i, 2) 'column 2
         j = j + 1
    End With
    
   
  xlwbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\File name (i want this to be value from userform text box")
  
  
  
   xl.DisplayAlerts = True
   
    'no need to carry on searching
    
Next i

End With
```

Comment: Thanks for input. however it still populate row 2 of column 8 and 9. i want to start populating information from row 23 in column 8 and 9.

Comment: Ok, I made changes to the code. I think this should work.

Comment: thanks. but still populate column from row 2 not 23.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to remove `.Offset(1).End(xlUp)`. Try again

Comment: thanks for your continues support. now values populate in row 1 instead of row 23